# Is there a way to obfuscate screenshot information in Selenium

Tags: selenium

Just wondering if there's a way to let Selenium know that I want to obfuscate for example input fields with login information, hide the sensitive information sort to say, when taking screenshots. I know that it's possible to screenshot specific element, but that would not be the case. Any other ideas?

Comment: You could either alter the screenshot img by finding the position of the element  and blacking it out or just taking screenshots prior to filling.

Comment: Yeah, also an option, but that would be a "little extra work" for about 50 tests running every 10 minutes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some suggestions on this when running this with runScript in Selenium IDE that I wanted to share with all of you. This is one of the options when you need to take a screenshots for investigations and don't want people to see the data.

[image: using runScript and changing type to password]

And this is what is being returned so people who see the screenshot has no possibility to see the data in the screenshots.

[image: input field with changed type to password]

As this was what I was looking for, I mark it as an answer. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to do this with Selenium.

Comment: Yeah. The only option would be to create a new function that somehow tells the screenshot engine to black out the input fields or AI... that would be overkill.

Comment: I mean if you want to black out a screen I have a demo for that. It's a tad overkill because it uses the location of the elements and stuff.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan does it blackens out a specific location where there is an input field? Or does it make the whole picture blurred or similar?

Comment: It just draws a black rectangle over the input with cv2.

Comment: Do you have a link to that demo? Would be really interesting to see.

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/nayisawuqu.apache It would go something like this with some changes to the y axis.